# FullPage.js and maps framework

Tags: jquery, maps, fullpage.js, yandex

I'm trying to use `Yandex maps` with the `fullPage.js` plugin.
The problem is that the problems are not loaded.
If I don't call this function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.fullpage({
    'verticalCentered': false
  });
});
```

maps will load.
I'm newbie in javascript, what i do wrong?

Comment: Do Yandex map require any javascript call? How do you load those maps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 100%, but the problem might be that those maps need some kind of javascript call and you are doing it before fullPage.js modifies the DOM structure of the site.

You have to consider that you want to load Yandex map dynamically. After fullPage.js changes the DOM. You might need to use [`afterRender`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterrender) callback:

> This is the callback you want to use to initialize other plugins or fire any code which requires the document to be ready

Not sure if this could be related with this topic:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682554